# Martini Go server with built in web crawler get too many open files after a few hourse

Tags: go

I built a web crawler that serves up some http info on its findings. The crawler runs as a go routine and martini runs the web server. After a while I start getting

```
2014/08/01 10:23:51 http: Accept error: accept tcp [::]:3000: too many open files; retrying in 1s.
```

I read I should try increasing the max open files only I am new to this level of configuration and have no idea how to do this. I am running this on Ubuntu 14.04. How do you change a martini servers max open files please and thank you.

Comment: Post some code. You are likely not closing the response bodies after you're done.

Comment: Which process is giving the error - the web server or the crawler?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you don't forget to close the response you get from an `http.Get`, as in [this issue](https://github.com/go-martini/martini/issues/199#issuecomment-37419136).

[This example](http://play.golang.org/p/vfPsfTNOhg) shows a better response management:

```
    resp, _ := http.Get("http://127.0.0.1:3000"+path)
    s, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    resp.Body.Close()
```

If the issue really still persists, then you can [try and increase the `fs.file-max` in `/etc/sysctl.conf`](https://wiki.magnolia-cms.com/display/WIKI/Too+Many+Open+Files).

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by moving the following code out side of the function:

```
var tr = &http.Transport{
    TLSClientConfig: &tls.Config{InsecureSkipVerify: true},
}
var client = &http.Client{Transport: tr}
```

Comment: This solved my problem too! I was stucked on ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body) but this was definitely the source of the issue. Thanks!

Comment: No matter what the language or framework, I will *always* downvote suggestions to skip verification of TLS certificates. It's a major hack and opens your code to man in the middle attacks. Don't follow this answer. Instead, figure out how to close your file handles correctly after you're done with them as soon as possible.